# SSIS Dynamic File Import to SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis

I have 8 ".txt" files, all with different columns that I would like to create a loop for in SSIS to import into separate  SQL Tables using dynamic naming. So like
"Static Text" +"FileName", where the FileName is variable.

I have made packages before that do this but they were only for files with static columns and they just appended to the same SQL table. I'm looking to create a new SQL table for each file ran through the loop now though.

Is there anyway to do this in SSIS? I have screenshotted some of my package below if anyone can suggest modifications. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't do this. SSIS needs to have to correct metadata (columns, data types etc.) at design time. You can't change them dynamically at run time.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a way to code this in SSIS? I've seen this done before, just not sure what else I need.

Comment: You should be able to extract column names from the text files, and use those names to build a dynamic sql statement to create the tables, then use an Execute SQL task to execute your prepared create table commands.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if you have many sources with different structure. because SSIS needs to have to correct metadata (columns, data types etc.) at design time.

But if you have tables with same structure you have to create one destination table (temp) and put it's name in your variable `VarFileName` and map columns in the `OLEDB Destination`. and you have to set your DataFlowTask property `DelayValidation`  to True. so metadata is not checked until the DataFlowTask is started executing.

Creating table should be done with `Execute SQL Task` using expressions (passing Tablename from variable)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Loop. Put Script Task then a DFT task in it as shown in the image.

[image: Image : 1]

2. Crate source and destination variable and assign some temp table name to them. These tables should exist. 
   [image]
3. script task will update the source and target table.
   follow the images

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am changing the source and destination table values to "dbo.T2" and "dbo.T4". But you have to change according to your requirement.